# Running process builder attempting to execute "source" command

Tags: java, process, ioexception, processbuilder

I'm running process builder and trying to source /etc/profile to be able to execute commands that work in a regular shell.

```
String args[] = {"source", "/etc/profile"};
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Unfortunately it returns:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "source": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe the `source` command is built into the shell, so you wouldn't be able to run it directly from java. Executing `bash` rather than `source` might do the trick.

Comment: @Wesley Yes `bash -c 'source /etc/profile'` will do the trick. Yet all the changes to the environment would be lost when bash process terminates. And anyway your process would not see them.

Comment: is there a way to get the standard shell environment into a process?